How many scram iterations should be set for PostgreSQL to ensure CLI level password security?
I am working on trying to build some foundational knowledge on secure deployments of PostgreSQL.  I'm currently on version 16.  While only one measure of security protocol, my first step is to secure passwords for users using SCRAM 256.  Given that the literature on this type of configuration is limited, I wanted to know what the recommendation is on the number of scram iterations that should be configured in my postgresql.conf file?
The default is 4096 and I don't fully understand what a larger number would do in terms of securing my database cluster.
I've read the postgresql official documentation, searched through stack overflow, done a number of google searches, and tried to review different YouTube videos on the topic.

SCRAM security.

@AdrianKlaver Thank you for posting this.  I recognize that the calculation is such that a modern machine should take a certain amount of time, but I'm hoping to get someone to comment on what that means in practice.  There is a Stack article from around 2015 or so, but it seems dated and with the same feedback.  Is there any way to expand on this?


Measure the time taken on the machine you have. 2. Adjust the number accordingly. There isn't much more to say without getting into the mechanics of the algorithm.


@RichardHuxton do you have any guidance on how to measure the time taken on my machine?  I'm trying to document a base methodology on minimum standards and such without having much to work with regarding documentation across the web.

? with a clock ? You seem to be struggling with this question
